# PHP datetime and strtotime got extra 3 minute

Tags: php, datetime

php date is get extra 3 minute after i use `strtotime` function. Please

```
<?php 
    $date=date('2014-03-03 09:00:00');
    $date1=strtotime($date);    
    echo date('Y-m-d h:m:i',$date1);
    ?>
```

output: 2014-03-03 09:03:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct format of datetime.

Replace `h:m:i` with `h:i:s`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
    $date=date('2014-03-03 09:00:00');
    $date1=strtotime($date);    
    echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$date1);
    ?>
```

you have used h:m:s , where m is month... :-)

Answer (score 1):

**You are using m which is a numeric representation of a month (from 01 to 12)**

**That's why you are getting 03**

change from

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:m:i',$date1);
```

to

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$date1);
```